# Install GPIO problem

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, shared-libraries

[image: --install-headers 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Include\RPi.GPIO' Check the logs for full command output. Error: process returned with code 1]
It seems like I cannot download GPIO...

Comment: You can't run RPi.GPIO on Windows, it's only compatible with Raspberry Pi hardware.

Comment: (1) So you are using Thonny MicroPython IDE on PC Window, to talk to Rpi Pico through a USB serial adaptor cable. Me too.  (2) I repeated your experiment to try to download Rpi.GPIO to my Pico. I got the warning message something like "Rpi.GPIO is not compatible to MicroPython or Circuit Python.", ... So I did not proceed. Let me explain why.

Comment: (2) For Rpi2/2/3/4, Rpi.GPIO is built in, there is no need to download, you just import it. And for Pico, You need to do the following to start using GP: ***from machine import Pin***.

Answer (score 7):

You can't install RPi.GPIO on Windows. If you want to mock GPIO calls on a PC, try gpiozero which has a mock pin interface: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_pins.html